# Why is the VSCommands.FindResults.Match coloring not changing when I edit it in Visual Studio's options?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I in visual studio go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> VSCommands.FindResults.Match and change the Item foreground and Item background colors but they never show in my Find Results output window.  I have closed visual studio, restarted my computer, etc. but it does not change.  Anyone know how to force this change to take place?